# Why switch execution plan for consecutive, identical queries?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

## This question is not about 'What should be'. The situation is the situation. I'm just seeking understanding (at this point).

Select statement specifies 13 fields to return but only provides five fields in the 'where' clause (one of which is empty). The query searches 20 records at a time appending each record to the query via an 'or' clause.

```
Int = integer  
Alpha = alphanumeric
 
SELECT Int1, Int2, Int3, PAN, Int4, Int5, Alpha1, Alpha2, Alpha3,
Int6, Alpha4, Int7, Alpha5 from table1 WHERE Int1 = 'NNNN' and Int2 =
'N' and Int3 = 'NN.NN' and PAN = 'NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN' and Int4 ='' and
Int5 = 'NNNNN' and Date1 >= '2016/02/25 01:00:00.000',Date1 <=
'2016/02/27 22:59:59.999' OR ***[REPEAT with minor variance X 19]***
```

The code this comes from is drawing on a dataset of some 60K (relatively uniform) records. Sales transactions to be more specific.

Almost all of the queries return good data in no time. This runs every day and takes about 15 minutes. This gives us 3000 queries of 20 records each at the approximate average rate of 3/second.

#### The problem occurs when the occasional query will time out after ~~44 seconds.

When asked, the DBA explained the queries that time out were running under another execution plan.

I'm trying to understand why the server will successfully use one execution plan, switch to another on the next query (~~0.3 seconds later) then switch back again(?) and carry on.

Thank you,

Comment: The query needs extra fields from a record we know exists. The only non-static value is the date range.  The database and table exist solely for this application so contention is not an issue. There are no/few new records written at that time of day.

Comment: You should look into using OPTION RECOMPILE as query hint and enabling `optimize for adhoc workload` sp_configure option. Seems like the rate at which those queries are run will bloat the plan cache.

Comment: Are the Int columns actually declared as integers? I'm asking this because in your conditions the values you are comparing those columns to are enclosed in quotation marks, as if they are strings, and in one case (`… Int3 = 'NN.NN' …`) the value doesn't even look like an integer – more like a real.

Comment: Before looking at the plan issue, I would first investigate why a query that uses 5 equality and 1 range conditions and returns only 20 rows needs 300 ms on average. There must be something wrong there - type mismatch, missing indexes, something ...

Comment: -found out there is no index on the table in question

Comment: Kin, will check out your suggestions. thanks

Comment: Andriy: Please don't take what I wrote as gospel. The 'NN.NN' was meant to represent 'N'umbers. The point is the query is requesting records we know exist in a schema we specified.

Comment: ypercube: The average end-to-end time of 0.3 seconds doesn't seem long if we take into account the DBMS is on a remote server.   This code runs at some ~~150 different clients without a hitch. This case is highly exceptional.

Comment: Sorry but this question is bad. Not bad in general but **bad for this site, in its current form.** There are many missing details, like the actual query used (Andriy commented and he's right `Int3 = 'NN.NN'` vs. `Int3 = 17` can be an issue with implicit conversions and affect the produced plans). You are not even sure if the table has indexes and what indexes. You haven't told us if the 300 ms is a query time or it includes network time. This leads to just wasting other people valuable time. You already have a good answer with useful details but it's speculative, with such a broad question.

Comment: So, please provide all those details, and if possible actual execution plans (both versions, the good and the bad) and we'll be happy to reopen the question. And you'll be happy because you'll get more detailed answers that actually answer your question, without speculations.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your query includes literal values (rather than being a prepared statement where the values change per execution) and assuming that the database isn't configured to force every literal to be treated as a bind variable (which has other side effects), the query

```
SELECT col1
  FROM table
 WHERE col2 = 'foo'
```

is completely different from

```
SELECT col1
  FROM table
 WHERE col2 = 'bar'
```

Each query would need to be parsed separately and each would generate (potentially) a different query plan.

When generating the query plan, the optimizer is going to use each of the literal values along with the statistics that have been gathered to guess at how many rows the query will return and which query plan would be most efficient for that estimate.  My guess is that some of the literal values cause the optimizer to estimate many more (or many fewer) rows than are really returned which causes the optimizer to produce a poor plan.

Simplifying drastically, let's say that the statistics on the table tell you that it has 150,000 rows.  Let's say it has a `date` column `dateCol` which is indexed so there is a statistic on it (and it alone).  And let's say that this statistic says that the data is uniformly distributed between 1/1/2015 and 3/31/2016 (15 months with 10,000 rows per month).  If I run the query

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE dateCol BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
```

the optimizer expects that I'm going to return 120,000 of the 150,000 rows.  In this case, it probably won't use the index on `dateCol`.  On the other hand,

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE dateCol BETWEEN '2016-03-01' and '2016-03-10'
```

would be expected to return about 3,000 rows and the optimizer would probably use the index on `dateCol`.  Of course, if your statistics are out of date-- perhaps you've added lots of data with a `dateCol` value in April 2016 and you purged all the 2015 data but the statistic hasn't been refreshed-- those estimates will be off and the database may choose the wrong plan.

In your case, my guess would be that depending on the different literal values, the optimizer guesses that different indexes would be more efficient.  If it expects that one of your predicates is really selective, for example, it may choose to use an index on that predicate rather than a different index.  If the optimizer's guess is wrong because statistics are stale or because different columns correlate in unexpected ways (say, rows with a recent `dateCol` value always have a `col2` value of "foo" and a `col3` value of 17 so specifying the latter two predicates doesn't really make the query more selective), the optimizer is likely to pick a less efficient query plan.  If the plan is slow enough, it will lead to the timeout error you are seeing.

Without delving too deeply, it's hard to know the right answer to your particular problem.  It could be that statistics are stale and just need to be refreshed.  It could be that new statistics are needed to capture exactly how different columns relate.  If you can, you probably want to move to using bind variables and prepared statements though that may create issues if the first execution happens to use a set of values that produce a poor cardinality estimate.  If this is in a stored procedure, you could use the `optimize for` hint to optimize the query for the (or at least a) "good" set of values.

Comment: That's brilliant. Especially since it gives me an avenue for investigation. What are the chances the set of 20 records is visibly different?

Comment: Rereading this it strikes me that we know exactly how many rows the query will return exactly 20 rows every time except possibly the last one if there less than 20 records left.

Comment: @NetScr1be - You may know that the query is going to return 20 rows.  It is unlikely that the database optimizer is going to guess that number correctly every time.  It is entirely possible that it will be close most of the time but occasionally it's going to guess way too high or way too low (cardinality estimates with multiple predicates that have different levels of correlation are tricky).  It is also possible that it is just flipping between different indexes.

Comment: So, is there a way to specify the number of rows expected?

Comment: @NetScr1be - If your comment that there are no indexes is correct, that would imply that there is only one possible query plan-- a table scan-- that the cardinality estimates are pointless and that the DBA's explanation is at least highly suspect and there is a lot more going on.  It seems highly unlikely that you are running repeated queries against a table with absolutely no indexes.  There isn't even a primary key?

Comment: @NetScr1be - Potentially, you could look at using a plan guide to force a particular plan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx or by specifying a particular index in a hint (assuming that you really have indexes).  Or the `optimize for` approach I suggested in my answer.

Comment: My understanding at this point (after speaking with the DBA this afternoon) is he wants to index the table indicating there isn't one. i'm waiting to hear from our people but I'm confident we specified an index at project time.